# How to rewrite a URL using .htaccess that contains multiple GET variables

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have used .htaccess to rewrite the URLs for all pages on my site except for this one;

```
https://www.atlasestateagents.co.uk/property_search.php?sort=3&availability=1&location=Liverpool&radius=50&min_price=&max_price=&min_beds=&max_beds=&type=&added=&available=1
```

I'm totally stuck on how to re-write this url because of the GET variables. I'd be happy with just replacing `property_search.php` to `property_search` and leaving the rest of the URL as it is.

My .htaccess file;

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.* 
RewriteRule .* ? [F,L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.atlasestateagents.co.uk/$1 [R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.atlasestateagents.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.atlasestateagents.co.uk/$1 [R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php 
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^about/?$ about.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^contact/?$ contact.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^landlords/landlord-services-and-fees/?$ landlords/landlord-services-and-fees.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^vendors/vendors-services-and-fees/?$ vendors/vendors-services-and-fees.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^property-([0-9]+)/(.*)?$ view_property.php?property_id=$1 [NC,L]

Options -Indexes 

ExpiresActive On

ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"

ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out for myself using the following code;

```
RewriteRule ^property-search/?$ property_search.php [NC,L,QSA]
```

The `QSA` is the main part as it appends the query string from the request to the substituted URL